# Does Flutter's FirestoreQueryBuilder automatically update when new documents are added in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can you configure Flutter's `FirestoreQueryBuilder` to automatically update when new documents are added to Firestore after the widge thas been built? (similar to the behavior of a Streambuilder)?

I prefer not to use Streambuilder for this feature in my application given that the built in pagination in the `FirestoreQueryBuilder` works better than the workaround pagination you can use with streambuilders (i.e. the document limits)

Comment: While I've never worked with `FirestoreQueryBuilder` myself, it is very uncommon for paginated readers to use realtime listeners, because of the number of edge cases that pop up when combining the two.

Comment: It turns out that the FirestoreQueryBuilder uses realtime listeners - extremely useful! Whenever I delete or add a document the UI updates automatically

Comment: Nice!  I might have to give that a try at some point. :)

Comment: @CharlesVanDamme, I found this [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/firestore/). can you go through these once?